# Error handling for Ruby Kernel method not working

Tags: ruby, error-handling, kernel

I have found myself in need to execute a string.  Current method is to use the `Kernel#eval()` method.  Everything is working fine, but my error handling isn't working.  For example, a missing closing quotation mark will completely kill and exit the program.

Here's an excerpt.  Any idea why I can't catch the error?

```
def process(str)
  print "\n"
  eval(str)
rescue => e
  puts e
end

>> process('"')
console.rb:90:in `eval': (eval):1: unterminated string meets end of file (SyntaxError)
        from console.rb:90:in `process'
        from console.rb:81:in `bouncer'
        from console.rb:14:in `block in prompt'
        from console.rb:11:in `loop'
        from console.rb:11:in `prompt'
        from console.rb:97:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/StandardError.html):

> A rescue clause without an explicit Exception class will rescue all StandardErrors (and only those).

[`SyntaxError`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/SyntaxError.html) is not a `StandardError`. To catch it, you have to be explicit, e.g.:

```
def process(str)
  print "\n"
  eval(str)
rescue Exception => e
  puts e
end

process('"')
```

Output:

```
(eval):1: unterminated string meets end of file
```

Comment: worked like a charm.  I didn't know that a blanket `rescue` clause _only_ catches a `StandardError`.  Thank you!

Comment: @m8ss it catches "all StandardErrors", i.e. `StandardError` and its subclasses. The documentation for [`Exception`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Exception.html) contains a class hierarchy.

Comment: Right.  Next time I have this issue, I will keep in mind the _class_ of the error.  Thanks again.